# How to set conditional filter in where clause using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a bolean condition called `accessories`

If it is true then I want to make sure that a cell value is not empty
otherweise it can be empty. I have the following:

```
var items = (from a in allRowsrows
        where accessories == true ?  a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "": a["MASTERID"].ToString() == "" &&
              a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString() ||
              a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
        select new ItemsToUpdate
        {
            isAccessory = accessories,
            Item = a
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Problem: 
Well simply put it does not filter correctly when using the above.

```
ITEMNO cell, `NEWITEMNO` cell are the same , LABEL cell and `NEWVISITEMNO` cell are also the same
```

and this should then give me a list with 0 items but I am still getting items in my list.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Modified code:

```
var items = (from a in allRows
                     where accessories == true ?  a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "": true &&
                      (a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString()) ||
                      (a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString())
                select new ItemsToUpdate
                {
                    isAccessory = accessories,
                    Item = a
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Still wrong filtering.

Comment: Put some brackets in, to accurately define precedence of logical operations

Comment: You are using both `||` and `&&` without parentheses - what is your expected query?

Comment: `WHERE a == 1 && (b == 2 || c== 3)` is not the same as `WHERE (a == 1 && b == 2) || c== 3`

Comment: You likely need parenthesis around the conditional as it has a lower precedence than `&&` and `||`

Comment: *If it is true then I want to make sure that a cell value is not empty otherweise it can be empty*, if that is your requirement then why do you have all the other conditions? Please tell us the full requirements to help you out.

Comment: First of thanks for the input. the parenthesis around the ||  conditions did not do the trick. For the question why I have several other conditions is because I have more than just the bolean BUT the bolean is making it so that the filtering is not correct.  @Enigmativity answer gave me what i was looking for but I am trying to understand where I vent wrong with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is why you are not getting the correct results. This condition:

```
where accessories == true ?  a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "": a["MASTERID"].ToString() == "" &&
          a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString() ||
          a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
```

means this:

*if accessories is true, then check if MASTERID is not empty. That is it. But, and this is where the bug is, if accessories is false, check this whole condition below:*

```
a["MASTERID"].ToString() == "" &&
a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString() ||
a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
```

which is evaluated like this:

```
(a["MASTERID"].ToString() == "" &&
 a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString()
)
OR
a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
```

In other words, if MASTERID is empty and ITEMNO is not the same as NEWITEMNO, it will never check LABEL.
Your edited code in your question makes no difference, it still means the same thing as above.

Now your question is why Enigmativity's answer gives you the correct results. Here is how he has it:

```
where accessories ? a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "" : true
where a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString() || a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
```

which means this:

*If accessories is true, then check if MASTERID is not empty. Otherwise use the value `true`. Also, check to make sure ITEMNO is not the same as NEWITEMNO OR LABEL is not the same as NEWVISITITEMNO.*

So essentially it is doing this:

```
(accessories ? a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "" : true)
&&
(
    a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString() || 
    a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
)
```

---

I don't know your full requirements but I am afraid even Enigmativity's answer may produce the wrong results (or may not). It all depends on when you will hit the specific case. Perhaps, my explanation can guide you.

Comment: Excellent and precise. Thank you, this explained things perfectly. Kind of obvious now but I guess it always is when you understand your mistake.

Comment: @thund3er Really glad it helped. It is Boolean logic so it gets tricky. I suggest studying *truth tables* if you want to learn more about such. And keep in mind that every programming language, including SQL (not a language per-se)  deals with booleans differently; especially the short-circuiting (important to learn what short-circuiting means) part.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
var items =
(
    from a in allRowsrows
    where accessories ? a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "" : true
    where a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString() || a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()
    select new ItemsToUpdate
    {
        isAccessory = accessories,
        Item = a
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: This gives me the correct filtering. I am having trouble understanding why two where clauses are needed? If you check my edit with modified code I would think that the solution should be similar to yours but  my edited code still gives me the wrong filtering.

Comment: @ThunD3eR - The two `where` clauses ensure the order of precedence for the conditions. Doing `where A && B || C` is vague - you could do `where A && (B || C)` or `where A where B || C`. I like the latter as it is cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to use brackets in your where clause?

```
       var items = (from a in allRows
                 where (accessories == true ?  a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "": true &&
                  (a["ITEMNO"].ToString() != a["NEWITEMNO"].ToString()) ||
                  (a["LABEL"].ToString() != a["NEWVISITEMNO"].ToString()))
            select new ItemsToUpdate
            {
                isAccessory = accessories,
                Item = a
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: Made no difference. Still get one value as with my original and modified code. 
@Enigmativity works perfectly, just trying to understand the need of two where clauses.

Comment: Try again with brackets around the `accessories == true ?  a["MASTERID"].ToString() != "": true`.